# How to make a timed automatic content toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, pageload

Hi here's the goal: to create an automatic bit of content that toggles open after a set period of time automatically on page load. I don't want any button or text to control the toggle, and it would be even better if it toggled back into nothingness after a set time!

I hope that makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) will accomplish your goals:

```
setInterval(functionName, milliseconds);
```

Example function:

```
function functionName() {
    $('.toggle-containers').toggleClass('visible');
}
```

[Little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jjv5f/)

Comment: Ok I think this is getting there. I was hoping for a slide-down effect like one often sees in toggle scenarios. I probably should have mentioned that!!